# Replace the whole string if it contains specific letters/character

Tags: python-2.7

Replace the whole string if it contains specific letters/character…

I have a text file (myFile.txt) that contains multiple lines, for example:

> The hotdog
>   The goal
>   The goat

What I want to do is the following:

If any word/string in the file contains the characters 'go' then, replace it with a brand new word/string ("boat"), so the output would look like this:

> The hotdog
>   The boat
>   The boat

How can I accomplish this in Python 2.7?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: What is the algorithm? You replace "The hotdog" even though it doesn't contain the characters "go" (at least not in that order), and your replacements are likewise not consistent: g->r on line 2, g->b on line 3

Comment: My bad there! "The hotdog" line wont be replaced because it does not contains "go". You are correct!

Comment: I just rephrase the question to make it simpler… I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Break this problem down into its components.  Do you know how to read a text file?  Do you know how to break a line into a list of words?  Do you know how to see if a word contains a substring?  Do you know how to replace an entry in a list?  And so on.  Each of those subquestions *already has many answers on SO*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *sounds* like you want something like this:

```
with open('myFile.txt', 'r+') as word_bank:
    new_lines = []
    for line in word_bank:
        new_line = []
        for word in line.strip().split():
            if 'go' in word:
                new_line.append('boat')
            else:
                new_line.append(word)
        new_lines.append('%s\n' % ' '.join(new_line))
    word_bank.truncate(0)
    word_bank.seek(0)
    word_bank.writelines(new_lines)
```

Open the file for reading and writing, iterate through it splitting each line into component words and looking for instances of 'go' to replace. Keep in list because you **do not** want to modify something you're iterating over. You will have a bad time. Once constructed, truncate the file (erase it) and write what you came up with. Notice I switched to sticking an explicit `'\n'` on the end because `writelines` will not do that for you.

Comment: This did it new_line.append("boat") but is not replacing the words ("goal", "goat") inside the file. Sorry! I'm new at this.

Comment: @elyoe011 It's ok. I'm not sure I understand the problem, though. Do you mean it's not replacing them in your original file? I didn't write back to it. I just used `print` so you could get an idea of the output.

Comment: Correct! Is not replacing them in the original file. All I wanted to do is... If it finds a word that contains "go" replace the whole word (the one that contains "go") with the word "boat"

Comment: I will try it as soon as I get a chance... Thanks!!

Comment: That code worked great! but... is adding new spaces/lines at the beginning of the file/first string... Any idea on how to remove them?

Comment: Sorry, you have to also add the `seek(0)` to go back to the beginning. I thought `truncate()` already did that but apparently it doesn't, which leaves a bunch of `NUL` chars at the beginning.

Comment: Perfect! You did it! Thanks a bunch!!